# CKEDITOR dataFilter apply rules on drop

Tags: ckeditor

I'm trying to set a style for every image tag that gets inserted into the editor to set it's width to 500px (for example).

So far if I paste the image from the clipboard it works fine, but it doesn't work for the drag and drop event, the dataFilter is not applying the rules.

here is my code:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (ev) {

            //Works on paste from clipboard
            ev.editor.dataProcessor.dataFilter.addRules({
                elements: {
                    img: function(e) {
                        e.attributes.style = 'width: 500px;';
                    }
                }
            });

            ev.editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules({
                elements: {
                    img: function(e) {
                        e.attributes.style = 'width: 500px;';
                    }
                }
            });

            ev.editor.on('paste', function(evt) {
                //do something maybe
            });

            ev.editor.document.on('drop', function (evt) {
                //do something maybe
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few days ago [CKEditor 4.5.0 Beta](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor-4.5-Beta-Released) was released and one of the features that it brings is an integration with native drag and drop. The new system is very powerful and consists of many new features, but you will be most interested in the fact that dropped content is passed through the [`editor#paste`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-paste) event and then, as usual, inserted into the editor by [`editor.insertHtml()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editable-method-insertHtml). This method uses the `editor.htmlDataProcessor.toHtml()` which runs the `editor.htmlDataProcessor.dataFilter`. In other words - you don't need to do anything - all pasted and dropped content will be automatically passed through the data filter.

So I recommend waiting for the final version of CKEditor 4.5.0. You can use the beta for now of course.

PS. I advise not to try to use older version of CKEditor and trying to handle drop manually (as you showed), because as we experienced ourselves this is terrifyingly hard due to lacking APIs (e.g. ability to get range from a drop position) and varying browser support for drag and drop. It took us many months to carve something that we could release :).

Comment: Awesome!, in relation to this question: I noticed that in Chrome I can't paste nor drop an image inside CKEDITOR, but I can actually obtain it through a very simple script, will the new version support pasting images from Chrome?

Comment: Did you read the [blog post](http://ckeditor.com/blog/CKEditor-4.5-Beta-Released) I linked, see the [screencast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B5DeL3aHmYU) or the [sample](http://ckeditor.com/tmp/4.5.0-beta/image-upload.html)? ;)

Comment: Srry, I was at work and didn't have much time, I'll take a look :D

Comment: Hello, coming back to this question, this is not working in CKEditor 4.5.0 when I drop/paste an img... the img in the document has the original width